# How to add an automatically generated coupon code to the welcome email

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, coupon-codes

I want to add an automatically generated coupon code to the welcome email. Each coupon code can only be used once. I don't know much about magento. Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269470/magento-2-new-user-give-the-discount/269491#269491)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 New user give the discount](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269470/magento-2-new-user-give-the-discount)